# NPM angular-maps bing clustering

Tags: maps, bing-maps, bing, markerclusterer

Using angular-maps (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-maps) module and not finding any documentation on how to cluster markers. Supposedly it supports Bing clustering but I cannot get it to work. Is it an option that is set on the IBOX or a boolean directly on the x-marker directive?

```js
this.iBox = IBox;

this._options = {
    disableBirdseye: true,
    disableStreetside: true,
    navigationBarMode: 1,
    //center: 'Microsoft.Maps.Location(54, -4)',
    mapTypeId: 'Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial',
    zoom: 2,
    disableScrollWheelZoom: true
};

this._box  = {
  maxLatitude: 48,
  maxLongitude: -86,
  minLatitude: 28,
  minLongitude: -98
  //center: 'Microsoft.Maps.Location(54, -4)',
};
```

```html
 <div id="myMap" style='width: 100%; height: 400px;'>
    <x-map #xmap [Options]="_options" [Box]="_box">
        <x-map-marker *ngFor="let marker of dataGrid" [Latitude]="marker.Latitude" [Longitude]="marker.Longitude" [IconInfo]="_iconInfo">
            <x-info-box [DisableAutoPan]="true" [Title]="marker.L_NAME">
                <x-info-box-action [Label]="'Click Me'" (ActionClicked)="_click()"></x-info-box-action>
            </x-info-box>
        </x-map-marker>
    </x-map>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, can you show us your code as a starting point?

Comment: Code added. Obviously it is not all of it but the part that pertains to the map.

Comment: Also the map seems to be working great and the markers showing properly. It is just the clustering that I am struggling with.

Comment: Without documentation you're usually better off finding a specific module for this.